# I do not understand how this function is editing the values in one of the arguments given to it

Tags: python, arrays, scope

So I am new to coding and I am really confused about what is happening. Basically I have a function that takes two arrays and is supposed to edit one based on the other. What is happening is I have two arrays defined and I give them to the function and somehow without having a return statement or anything the values of the arrays outside of the function change to what the values of the array within the function are. Also neither of the arrays are global so I am very confused. Here is the code if anyone is curious:

This is the function, it does not have a return statement:

```
def updateValueArray(valArray, posArray):
    for x in range(9):
        for y in range(9):
            options = 0
            optionValue = 0
            for i in range(9):
                if posArray[x,y,i]:
                    options+=1
                    optionValue = i+1
            if options == 1:
                valArray[x,y] = optionValue
```

And this is the place where the function is called, the print statements show that the values changed
even though I did not redefine them:

```
posabilityArray = findHiddenSingles(posabilityArray)
print(valueArray)
updateValueArray(valueArray,posabilityArray)
print(valueArray)
```

The output of the print statements:

```
[[0 4 1 0 0 0 0 9 6]
 [0 0 0 0 8 0 0 0 7]
 [0 6 0 0 7 0 2 0 0]
 [0 0 0 3 0 7 0 0 4]
 [0 0 3 0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [4 0 0 1 0 9 0 0 0]
 [0 0 6 0 1 0 0 5 0]
 [2 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0]
 [8 5 0 0 0 0 3 7 0]]
[[3 4 1 2 2 2 5 9 6]
 [3 2 2 2 8 1 4 1 7]
 [3 6 5 4 7 1 2 1 1]
 [5 1 2 3 2 7 5 2 4]
 [5 2 3 2 2 2 1 2 2]
 [4 2 2 1 2 9 5 2 2]
 [3 3 6 2 1 2 4 5 2]
 [2 1 9 6 4 6 6 1 1]
 [8 5 9 2 2 2 3 7 1]]
```

I would expect them to be the same because I am never changing the valueArray
Can anyone explain what is happening?

Comment: What do you think the assignment to `valArray[x, y]` does?

Comment: The problem may related with "Soft copy vs Hard copy"

Comment: @Barmar I think it changes to values in the local array valArray but it also seems to affect the array that is put into the function